# Example of non reduced scheme with reduced subscheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am looking for a non reduced scheme X, and a dense open set U of X such that the induced subscheme on U is reduced.

My idea is this: Let $X=Spec R$ where $R$ is not reduced, and then let $U=D(f)$ for some $f$. The induced scheme would be $Spec R_f$, and I would like $Spec R_f$ to be a reduced scheme.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The ideal (y^2,xy) gives you a line in the plane with an unreduced point.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Can you elaborate more? What ring are you considering?

Comment: The rings are $k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$ and its localization at $(y)$.

Comment: I suggest you browse something like Eisenbud's *The Geometry of Schemes* to learn some geometry before you are irrecoverably covered by scheme theory.